# I want to get an element tag printed in the console just by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to get an element tag printed in the console just by clicking on it but it doesn't seem to work and I don't get why?

can anyone point the error in my logic?

```
let bodyChildren = document.body.children;
let bodyArr = Object.values(bodyChildren);

for (i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) {
    bodyArr[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(bodyArr[i].tagName);
    };
}
```

Comment: You should make the function a recursive one since.  The current code will not necessary work for the children's children (ie it will not work for the entire DOM in your page)

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: okay, thanks for the reference appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get ALL elements from the document body and this is KEY: var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

```js
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
let bodyArr = Object.values(all);

for (i = 0; i < bodyArr.length; i++) {
    bodyArr[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.tagName);
    };
}
```

```html
<span>Hello world</span>
```

Comment: yeah this one seems neat and works  better

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you define a function, everything in it is contained in a separate scope. Within the function `bodyArr` is not known. You can use `this` instead to refer to the clicked element, like below:

`document.body.children` will only refer to the direct children of the `body` element. If you want to refer to every element in the DOM, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` instead.

When the code is written globally, like in the snippet below, the variable `bodyArr` is actually available in the global scope, as is the variable `i`. But keep in mind that the code inside the function is only executed when an element is clicked. At that point in time the `for` loop has been fully executed leaving `i` with the value `3` (since in the snippet below the `script` tag also counts). `bodyArr` will always contain exactly 1 element less, no matter how many elements are in the DOM. In this case it has 3 elements with the last element being saved at position 2 (zero based) in the array, hence `bodyArr[i]` equals `undefined`.

```js
let bodyChildren = document.body.children;
let bodyArr = Object.values(bodyChildren);
for (i = 0; i < bodyChildren.length; i++) {
      bodyArr[i].onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.tagName);
      }
}
```

```html
<span>child1</span>
<p>child2</p>
```

Comment: You got the right answer.  This can be improved as it only works for top-level elements only (will not work for the entire DOM)

Comment: I thought bodyArr is in the global scope so the function can work with it

Comment: @zaydmerzougui see my editted answer for an explanation as to why it still does not work eventhough the variable is indeed available in the global scope.